# How to set up a callback for contact event? ( ConnectContact() being deprecated )

Tags: contact

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

Is there a new way to set up a callback function in case of a contact, similar to the deprecated ConnectContact()? Or I have to add a ContactSensor to the model?

I am using Gazebo 1.8.0.

Thanks,
Andrei

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2926/how-to-set-up-a-callback-for-contact-event?-(-connectcontact()-being-deprecated-)/) by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 2108 on 2013-05-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You have to use the [ContactManager](http://gazebosim.org/api/2.2.1/classgazebo_1_1physics_1_1ContactManager.html), as seen in this [example](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/67961925fae73df9f9d7692daab0cc8167943769/gazebo/sensors/ContactSensor.cc?at=default#cl-113)

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2014-02-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0